# Weil Conjectures for Grassmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, characteristic-p, zeta-functions, weil-conjectures

To establish the Weil conjectures for $n$-dimensional projective space over a finite field is elementary. Does there exist a simple direct proof of the conjectures for finite field Grassmannians?

Comment: More generally, as Ben's answer notes, it's easy to do the point counts for varieties that have nice cell decompositions.  So generalized flag varieties and toric varieties are other examples where there should be direct proofs.  Maybe someone who knows Weil's original paper can comment: I thought that homogeneous spaces were one of his motivating examples?

Comment: Weil did this on the last paragraph of the paper where he states the Weil conjectures.

Comment: Reference http://www.ams.org/bull/1949-55-05/S0002-9904-1949-09219-4/home.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first result on the google search "zeta function of grassmannian" seems to contain quite a direct and not too long derivation of the zeta function for a grassmannian over a finite field:

http://www.math.mcgill.ca/goren/SeminarOnCohomology/GrassmannVarieties%20.pdf

From the zeta you see that it is rational, of course get the zeros (which are none), but you don't immediately get confirmation of the functional equation. Though, from the very simple combinatoric representation of the zeta function, it might be easy to prove directly, I will try with pen and paper later.

I'm glad I searched this, I didn't know the zeta was so simple in this case as well

Comment: A question that just occurred to me: There exist Grassamnians that are not projective varieties? if so, does the formulation of the Weil conjectures still trouble free?

Comment: @John: What do you mean? The usual Grassmanians (subspaces of a fixed dimension in a vector space of a given dimension) is always projective.

Comment: Why? Is it obvious?
What does the comment in the wikipedi article The simplest "Grassmannian that is not a projective space is Gr2(4)"  mean?

Comment: I know that you can embed a Grassmannian into projective space via the Plucker map, but it is not obvious to me that its image is the set of zeros of some ideal.

Comment: A projective variety is a closed subvariety of a projective space. 

Comment: ok, yes, closed wrt the Zariski topology is not the same as the zeros of an ideal.

Comment: It's not obvious, but it's true. Proof 1: Grassmannian's are proper, so the image of the Plucker embedding is closed. Proof 2: There are classic, explicit equations called the Plucker relations which cut out the Grassmannian. For a detailed and elementary proof that the Grassmannian is exactly the zeroes of the Plucker equations, see  Ezra Miller and Bernd Sturmfels' book.

Comment: What? Yes, this is precisely what Zariski closed means. (A homogenous ideal, when you are talking about projective space.)

Comment: Yes, yes, of course, the topology generated by the closed sets is equal to the closed sets, not something bigger.

Comment: @John: what Wikipedia means is that the simplest grassmanian which is not *isomorphic* to a projective space is $G(4,2)$, not that that is the simpler grassmanian which is not a *projective variety* (in which case we should correct it!)

Answer (score 11):

Yes.  Both cohomology and number of points are readily determined by looking at the Schubert cells (a cell of dimension k contributes one dimension to $H^{2k}$, and $q^k$ to the point count) and they match.

In fact, it's very easy to check Weil's conjecture directly for any smooth variety which has a decomposition into cells.

Comment: Cells in what sense?

Comment: in the sense of a CW decomposition, I think, when you work over the complex numbers

Comment: But doesn't every smooth manifold have a CW decomposition by Morse theory?

Comment: The cells are affine spaces inside the variety, which stratify it, not CW cells.  For example $\mathbb{P}^n = \mathbb{C}^n \cup \mathbb{C}^{n-1} \cup \ldots \cup \mathbb{C}^0$.

Comment: Kevin-  Think about an elliptic curve.

Comment: Ben, you are talking about complex dimension and so want H^{2k}.